# things_add method in seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working some legacy code right now in `seeds.rb`.  The previous developer used a method like this to add rows to the tables:

```
things_holder.oldthings_add(name)
```

where:

#### oldthings.rb

```
belongs_to :things_holder
```

#### things_holder.rb

```
has_many :oldthings
```

I can manipulate the object they created and adjust the seeds of the models they'd created. However, when I try to do the same to a model that I created myself (newthings), I can't seem to make it work.

Instead I get:

> undefined method: newthings_add

where does this `things_add` method come from? I don't see it in any of the `oldthings.rb` files

Comment: Where the `things_add` method is called, add something like `puts method(:things_add).source_location`. Then, in your console, you should see where the method is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*_add` is not a standard Rails / Active Record method, so it's either defined somewhere in your application, or it's provided by some other gem.

As @jvillian's commented, you may be able to `things_holder.method(:oldthings_add).source_location` to learn where the method is defined.

If that doesn't work, you could try passing a blatantly invalid value to the method (e.g. `things_holder.oldthings_add(true)`), and see where the backtrace points.

Comment: Thank you! both of these methods worked! it was being defined in thingsholder.rb  :)