# is there a guide/documentation for seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a page describing the conventions of seeds.rb?  I think I made it through all the guides but I still can't find a page describing how seeds.rb is supposed to work.

I'm setting up to work on a new project and new machine and I'm expecting to need to work through several errors similar to the one below. I'm still new to rails and I'm having trouble determining if it's a ruby or rails issue.

[things_add method in seeds.rb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863267/things-add-method-in-seeds-rb)

Is seeds.rb pure ruby talking to the DB?

TIA

Comment: What's the following error?, consider we shouldn't jump from one question to another one.

Comment: My question is about how to find information about seeds.rb  the link is just for context (and it's also now resolved)

Comment: Unfortunately we can not help with that. If your problem would have a specific question it'd fit here, otherwise is considered an off-topic question. Feel free to modify your question if it does.

Comment: fair enough, I've made a couple edits and responded to the answer that was given.  Please let me know if that is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seeds.rb` is just a Ruby file, nothing special, except that it's executed as part of the `rake db:seed` task.

You can put whatever code in there you want so long as it only makes use of methods and classes it has defined, or have been defined in your greater application.

The reason it's not very well documented is because there's really no rules here. You can put in there whatever you want. It's quite common to have loops, helper methods, and so on, depending on the complexity of your seeding process.

The only "rule" I'd mention is that it's expected that the `rake db:create && rake db:seed` combination reliably works both now and in the future. It's very easy to forget about your `seed.rb` file and long after it's been created and used you break something in it with a code change.

It's worth testing that this file still works once in a while if you're going to pack up this project and need to start from scratch now and then, or have new developers periodically joining the project that don't want to have to debug old mistakes.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think the set-up on a new machines issue is what I'm facing here.  I should have mentioned it in the question.